# Bind DataGridCell style directly to its contents

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `StatusCell` style for `DataGridCell` that I would like to use in several place in my application. I would like to externalize the `Style` tag so that I can reuse it easily without having to duplicate the code in my XAML everywhere.

Every other source I've found has required me to bind the trigger off the property from my ViewModel. But across the application, the column might be bound to `MyStatusProperty` or `SubObject.MyStatusProperty`, etc, so I want to do this to allow me to have one style that will apply to all of these without having to specify where it's binding from.

I am able to do this with a TextBlock with the following style. This lets me bind the `TextBlock` to whatever I want and the style binding doesn't matter where it's coming from.

```
<Style x:Key="StatusLabel" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Completed">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and when I create a textblock that I want to use this styling, all I have to do is

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource StatusLabel}" Text="{Binding Whatever}" />
```

But with a `DataGridCell` it doesn't let me do this

```
<Style x:Key="StatusCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="Completed">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding MyStatusProperty}" 
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource StatusCell}" />
```

I also tried setting up the trigger like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Reviewed">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But neither of these work. I have also tried swapping out "Content" in the last example for "Binding" and "Text"

**Is there another property I can bind to in the `DataGridCell` that will let bind the style trigger to the contents of the cell without knowing the binding path?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I found a workaround shortly after asking. Since it's working with TextBlocks, I just have to use TemplateColumns instead of TextColumns, although I'd still prefer to be able to use TextColumns since they'd use 6 less lines of XAML.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}" Style="{StaticResource StatusCellTextBlock}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Using the style:

```
<Style x:Key="StatusCellTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Completed">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```